# Can not append a div after Axios Call

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I have looked up previous questions asked on this forum and I did not find anything that is relevant to this specific situation. I am trying to create a user card from data I am pulling from Github. When I try to append the fist child div to the parent div that exists in the HTML my code throws the following error "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." Problem is it definitely IS a node. Here is my code.

```
    //Axios call
    const info = axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => createCard(data));

    function createCard(gitHubData) {
  const cards = document.querySelector(".cards");

  //Creating the elements for the cards
  const card = document.createElement("div").classList.add("card");
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  const info = document.createElement("div").classList.add("card-info");
  var name = document.createElement("h3").classList.add("name");
  var username = document.createElement("p").classList.add("username");
  var location = document.createElement("p");
  var profile = document.createElement("p");
  var followers = document.createElement("p");
  var following = document.createElement("p");
  var bio = document.createElement("p");

  //Creating the nested layout of our elements
  cards.appendChild(card);  //code fails here
  card.appendChild(img);
  card.appendChild(info);
  info.appendChild(name);
  info.appendChild(username);
  info.appendChild(location);
  info.appendChild(profile);
  info.appendChild(followers);
  info.appendChild(following);
  info.appendChild(bio);

  //Assigning the cards to info collected from axios
  img.src = gitHubData.avatar_url;
  console.log(img.src);
  name = gitHubData.name; //If I use .innerHTML or .textContent returns 
                          //undefined
  console.log(name);
  username = gitHubData.login;
  location = gitHubData.location;
  profile = `Profile: ${gitHubData.html_url}`;
  followers = gitHubData.followers;
  following = gitHubData.following;
  bio = gitHubData.bio;

  return cards;
}
```

Comment: did you confirm that the `const cards = document.querySelector(".cards");` is null or not?
if it is null you need to handle it

Comment: Did you try to append from the lowest level child element to cards?

Comment: Yes cards is a div and has the class of header

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why my code failed in the first place but I shut down my computer for the night and tried again in the morning. The correct code (which I tried before unsuccessfully was the following:

```
name.textContent = gitHubData.name;
username.textContent = gitHubData.login;
location.textContent = gitHubData.location;
profile.textContent = `Profile: ${gitHubData.html_url}`;
followers.textContent = gitHubData.followers;
following.textContent = gitHubData.following;
bio.textContent = gitHubData.bio;
```